# Plotting lat/long over shapefile not working in python

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a lat/long points from a csv file over a shapefile in python. this is my code

```
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))
    #sfstreets.plot(ax= ax, alpha = 0.4, color="grey")
    geo_dfstat19.plot(ax = ax, markersize = 20, color = "red", marker = "o", label = "Station")
```

when I run it this is what i get

[image: points and shapefile]

when i run just the lat/long this is what i get

[image: points]

when i run just the shapefile this is what i get

[image: shapefile]

the goal is to overlay these two images but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing coordinate systems. Your shapefile has a projected coordinate system with values from thousands on X-axis and millions on Y-axis. But your points look like are using a geographic coordinate system maybe in WGS with values between -180 and 180 on X-axis and -90 to 90 on Y-axis.

To solve that first try to convert all sources to the same coordinate system.

Comment: In addition to @AugustoSisa: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html

Comment: definitely read the docs as @RJAdriaansen suggests. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400751/115384 for an example implementation

Comment: looks like you need to change you shape file EPSG:4326